# Fetching data from 2 database from SQL server to R

Tags: r, sql-server-2008, qsqlquery

I have been trying to link SQL server to R from multiple databases but i am getting the following error

```
42000 156 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
42000 102 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'B'.
42000 102 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'C'.
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect
```

Am trying the following query

```
dbConnect <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=server1;database=MarketData;database=BusinessData;trusted_connection=true')
Daily_Date <- sqlQuery(dbConnect,paste('select A.BusinessDate, MAX(B.RecordDate) as LastDividendDate,
+ MIN(C.RecordDate) as NextDividendDate from
+ (select  BusinessDate, SUM(Quantity) QOL
+ from BusinessData..TradeData 
+ where ID = 1729903 and BusinessDate >= as.Date("2016-02-24")
+ group by BusinessDate) A
+ left outer join
+ (SELECT RecordDate
+ FROM MarketData..DivData
+ where ID = 1729903) B
+ on A.BusinessDate >= B.RecordDate
+ left outer join
+ (select RecordDate from MarketData..DivData
+ where InstrumentID = 1729903) C
+ on A.BusinessDate <= C.RecordDate
+ group by A.BusinessDate
+ order by A.BusinessDate'))
```

the same query is working in SQL server but not working in R
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try to isolate which part of the query is not working by shortening it. Maybe it is the "as" which causes problems. Maybe the renaming of the data.tables.

Comment: ok sure will try ! is it correct to define 2 databases in the first line of the code ?

Comment: Actually, I don't know. My gut feeling would say "no".